# Stop files from being uploaded via input

Tags: javascript, input, upload

Not able to clear upload values from input.  I have tried removing input from DOM then replacing it with another input having same id.  But when form submits the files that were in the old input are still being uploaded.  Do upload values need to be cleared in some other way?

```
 <input id="input1" type="file"></>
 <div id="div1" style="background-color:blue" onclick=removeEl()>remove</div>

 <script>
 function removeEl(){
 alert(document.getElementById('input1').id) 
 var a = document.getElementById('input1').parentNode;

 (a).removeChild(document.getElementById('input1'));

 alert(typeof document.getElementById('input1'))

 var newEl=document.createElement('input');
  newEl.setAttribute('id','input1');
  newEl.setAttribute('name','images[]');
  newEl.type = 'file';

 a.appendChild(newEl)

 submitForm();
 }
```

Basically I remove input element before form is submitted and add new element.  Even after removing input the upload file still is being collected.  I also noticed that on second alert after el is removed I always get 'object' instead of 'undefined'.

Not trying to reset the whole form!

Comment: You should post a code sample, it's probably a security issue

Comment: Show us the code you are using to attempt this please.